# Hibernate search wildcard did not return expected value

Tags: java, hibernate, lucene, hibernate-search

I've a field defined in my model as :

```
@Column(name = "name")
@Field(index = Index.YES, analyze = Analyze.YES, store = Store.NO)
private String name;
```

and my query is

```
public Result search(String term, int offset, int limit) {
    WildcardQuery regexQuery = new WildcardQuery(new org.apache.lucene.index.Term("name", "*" + term + "*"));

    QueryBuilder qb = getFullTextSession().getSearchFactory().buildQueryBuilder().forEntity(Company.class).get();
    org.apache.lucene.search.Query query =
            qb.bool().should(qb.phrase().onField("address.street").sentence(term).createQuery())
            .should(regexQuery)
            .createQuery();

    FullTextQuery hibQuery = getFullTextSession().createFullTextQuery(query, Company.class);

    hibQuery.setFirstResult(offset);
    hibQuery.setMaxResults(limit);

    Result result = new Result();
    result.total = hibQuery.getResultSize();
    result.items = hibQuery.list();

    return result;
}
```

I've a value in database (also indexed) 'Intersprint GmbH.'. If i call the method :

search("Interspr");

i expect to get this entity but result was empty. Any suggestion how can i build a "contains" query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is capitalization. I assume that "Intersprint GmbH" is indexed as two tokens - "intersprint" and "gmbh" (all lowercase, because an analyzer got applied. At query time you use a WildcardQuery with a given term "Interspr". There is no analyzer applied in this case, meaning you have no match between the lower cased "intersprint" and the wildcard query "*Inter*". You can confirm this by checking the index with Luke.

As a solution you can either use a QueryParser (which also uses the analyzer) or you use *QueryBuilder#keyword#wildcard()* which also will apply the analyzer. In the latter case the right analyzer should even be picked transparently for you.